# A bug in rails? About model inherited

Tags: ruby-on-rails, typeerror, dup, inherited

```
My env: ruby-1.9.2-preview3; rails-3.0.0.beta3
```

---

```
class PostFather < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.inherited(subclass)
  end
end

class Post < PostFather
end
```

---

In the console:

---

```
> Post.new # => TypeError: can't dup NilClass
> Post.all # => TypeError: can't dup NilClass
> Post.scoped # => TypeError: can't dup NilClass
```

---

You can try it yourself;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveRecord is using the inherited method, you need to call super so the ActiveRecord stuff still runs:

```
class PostFather < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.inherited(subclass)
    super(subclass)
  end
end
```